# Java calculate days in year, or between two dates

Tags: java, calendar, leap-year

Is there a method in any native Java class to calculate how many days were/will be in a specific year? As in, was it a [Leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) (366 days) or a normal year (365 days)?

Or do I need to write it myself?

I'm calculating the number of days between two dates, for example, how many days left until my birthday. I want to take into account the February 29 of Leap year. I have it all done except that 29th.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## since **JAVA 8**

Days in a year:

```
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("2020-12-31");                   // import java.time.LocalDate;
return d.lengthOfYear();                                       // 366
```

Days to my birthday:

```
LocalDate birth = LocalDate.parse("2000-02-29");
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();                             // or pass a timezone as the parameter

LocalDate thisYearBirthday = birth.withYear(today.getYear());  // it gives Feb 28 if the birth was on Feb 29, but the year is not leap.
LocalDate nextBirthday = today.isAfter(thisYearBirthday)
    ? birth.withYear(today.getYear() + 1)
    : thisYearBirthday;

return DAYS.between(today, nextBirthday);                      // import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;
```

Comment: OP says "...calculating the number of days between two dates"

Comment: You are right. I stand corrected and deleted my Comment. I edited the title of the Question to make it clear and complete.

Answer (score 50):

Another way to do it is to ask the `Calendar` class for the actual maximum days in a given year:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(new Date());

int numOfDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println(numOfDays);
```

This will return 366 for a bisestile year, 365 for a normal one.

Note, I used `getActualMaximum` instead of `getMaximum`, which will always returns 366.

Comment: @NoodleofDeath Actually, this Answer was outdated as of Java 8 in 2014. The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque I agree that if at all possible, you should use the java.time classes. But for those of us who don't have the luxury of using Java 8 yet this answer is not outdated. The OP was referring to java.util.Calendar and java.util.Date, and this answer is still very applicable for many of us. It was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @SamuraiSoul Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 and Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. So there is no reason to suffer with the wretched legacy `Date`/`Calendar`/etc. classes. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322497/642706) for details.

Answer (score 28):

## tl;dr

```
Year.of( 2015 ).length()
```

…and…

```
Year.isLeap( 2015 )
```

## `java.time.Year`

In Java 8 and later we have the [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html))

### `length`

The `Year` class represents a single year value. You can interrogate its length.

```
int daysInYear = Year.of( 2015 ).length();
```

### `isLeap`

You can also ask if a year is a Leap year or not.

```
Boolean isLeapYear = Year.isLeap( 2015 );
```

As an example, get the number of days in year using Java’s [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), such as:

> minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;

In our case, we want number of days of year. That is 365 for non-Leap years, and 366 for Leap year.

```
int daysInYear = ( Year.isLeap( 2015 ) ) ? 366 : 365 ;
```

### Day-of-year

You can get the day-of-year number of a date. That number runs from 1 to 365, or 366 in a leap year.

```
int dayOfYear = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ).getDayOfYear() ;
```

Going the other direction, get a date for a day-of-year.

```
Year.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).atDay( 159 ) ;
```

You could determine elapsed days by comparing these day-of-year numbers when dealing with a single year. But there is an easier way; read on.

### Elapsed days

Use the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum to calculate elapsed days.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 2 , 23 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , 3 , 11 ) ;
int daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop );
```

Automatically handles [Leap Year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
- See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: That's nice, but DON'T "tweak" my English.

Comment: you, sir, win the medal  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The `GregorianCalendar` standar class has an `isLeapyear()` method. If all you've got is a year number (say, `2008`), then construct a date using [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor, and then check the `isLeapYear()` method afterwards.

Comment: Bah. Stupid Java and its libraries for EVERYTHING. :-P (+1)

Comment: Yeah, using libraries for dates SUCKS. Passing your own tests for leap years, varying months, leap seconds, additive math is the way to... nevermind. :)

Comment: But, then you can easily just define the "MyCalendar" as being the new standard, and it'd magically pass all relevant tests.

Comment: @Autocracy: Only the built-in date libraries suck. Ask Jon Skeet about it.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this in late evening and I forgot to mention that I'm using the Calendar class and the Calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) to calculate the difference. I have only one doubt - if I do, for example, Calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 14) will it set the resulting year as a leap year if it is one? Or all years have only 365 days there?

Comment: It should, and it's easy enough to test. Set a date in a known leapyear and cross over the Feb 29th with your addition.

Comment: Yeap, it does. No need for GregorianCalendar then, I'll be using what I was using until now and calculate the remainder with the TimeUnit.DAYS.convert().

Answer (score 6):

For DateTime calculations I highly recommend using the [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library. For what you need, in particular, it would be a one liner:

```
Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Not interested in implementing a whole library just for doing one simple calculation.

Answer (score 5):

[GregorianCalendar.isLeapYear(int year)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isLeapYear%28int%29)

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) for some very nice pseudocode:

```
if year modulo 400 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else if year modulo 100 is 0
       then not_leap_year
else if year modulo 4 is 0
       then is_leap_year
else
       not_leap_year
```

I'm sure you can figure out how to implement that logic in Java. :-)

Comment: That looks like re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, agreed, this is before I knew about Java's `GregorianCalendar` class. Java's MANY other date/time issues aside, that's the way to go in this case!

Comment: why the down-vote? This is "the" algorithm to find leap year.

Comment: @Cem Catikkas: It's definitely correct, but the question is "was it a helpful answer". This is a Java question, so I can see an argument for using Java libraries being a better answer and reinventing the wheel being bad. Thanks for the upvote though! :-)

Answer (score 3):

You exact use case might be best solved with Joda and this specific [example](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TimeUnit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class. For your specific needs this should do:

```
public static int daysBetween(Date a, Date b) {
    final long dMs = a.getTime() - b.getTime();
    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(dMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Honestly, I don't see where leap years play any role in this calculation, though. Maybe I missed some aspect of your question?

*Edit:* Stupid me, the leap years magic happens in the `Date.getTime()`. Anyway, you don't have to deal with it this way.