# How to declare a method with 2 parameters of different types in the main method in java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

If i have this method: `public static int numberMonth(int parseMonth, String leapYear)`

how would i print it out in this method:

```
public static  void main(String[] args)
{
  Boolean correctDate = false;
  String date;

  while (!correctDate)
  {
    // It is OK to embed the way you called the method checkInput(getInput())
    // but for troubleshooting, it is easier for me to break into smaller steps.

    // Request Date and get user response
    date = getInput();

    // Verfiy that the date entered contains a valid........
    correctDate = checkInput(date);

    // Display meesage to user
    if (correctDate == true)
    {
      System.out.println("The date you entered is: " + date);
      System.out.println(numberMonth); 
      System.out.println("The numerical date: " );
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter valid date ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: the question title and body don't seem to match. can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: `int nextmonth = MyClass.numberMonth(month, "some string");
    System.out.println("Next month : " + nextmonth);`

Comment: What do `parsemonth` and `leapYear` signify?

Comment: @spookyjon 'public static String leapYear(String input) and public static int parseMonth(String input)

Answer (score 2):

Looking on your previous questions and code snippets I think you need to read something like Oracle/Sun Java Tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html
There are all answers in fact. And much more.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do what you've asked is to change `System.out.println(numberMonth)` to the following:

```
System.out.println(numberMonth(anInt, aString));
```

Where `anInt` is an `int` and `aString` is a string.  You could also do this with specific values, like so:

```
System.out.println(numberMonth(5, "leap"));
```

There's a much larger issue at play here, being that it seems you lack a foundation in the most basic aspects of Java syntax.  I would highly recommend taking a class, checking out an online tutorial, or getting a book to learn the basics of computer programming in general and the Java language more specifically.

For instance, in your [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443693/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-this-code-for-java-or-to-make-it-cleaner) where you show the `numberMonth` function in detail, while a lot of things stand out, the most striking detail is using a `String` for your `leapYear` value.  When you're dealing with information that is either true or false, you want to use the [boolean data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type).  Boolean variables can only contain two values: `true` or `false`.  So, rather than storing a string with the values `"leap"` or `"no leap"`, you could declare a boolean variable.  Here's a brief example:

```
public static int numberMonth(int parseMonth, boolean leapYear)
{
    if(leapYear)
    {
        //if leapYear is true, this code will be executed
    }
    else
    {
        //if leapYear is false, this block will be executed
    }
}
```

Take the time now to learn these basic, fundamental techniques. It will save you a mountain of frustration and wasted time in the future.

Comment: I am currently taking a class on java. This is a project I am currently working on implementing methods. The scope of the project is to take an input of MM/DD/YYYY and convert it into a month, day year and then the number of the date in a 365 number. if you want to look and see exaclty where I am coming from, I am more than willing to share the code with you